# (awaitable) task, not all code paths return a value

Tags: c#, list, async-await

Ok My employee object has a list of EmployeePayHistories which are displayed in a datagrid. I have a method to get the selected row from the datagrid and here I am trying to actually implement the function. However on the DeleteEmployeePayHistories() part its giving me an error saying its awaitable. I would love to know how to fix it, and why its doing it. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
    private Task DeleteEmployeePayHistories()
        {
           Employee.EmployeePayHistories.Remove(SelectedPayHistory);
           SelectedPayHistory = null;
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

Your method should either return a `Task` (probably `Task.CompletedTask`) or use the `async` keyword and `await` something.

```
private Task DeleteEmployeePayHistories()
{
    Employee.EmployeePayHistories.Remove(SelectedPayHistory);
    SelectedPayHistory = null;
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

or

```
private async Task DeleteEmployeePayHistories()
{
    // something in here should use await or you'll get another warning
    Employee.EmployeePayHistories.Remove(SelectedPayHistory);
    SelectedPayHistory = null;
}
```

Finally, if you have no need for async code, you could just make your method `void`

```
private void DeleteEmployeePayHistories()
{
    Employee.EmployeePayHistories.Remove(SelectedPayHistory);
    SelectedPayHistory = null;
}
```

Comment: Ok so If I'm calling my DeleteEmployeePayHistories method when a button is pressed would that mean I need to return a task?

Comment: @brock its not the button that means it needs to return a task, its the fact that youve made the method have a return type of `Task`.

Comment: Ok so I'm not trying to return anything, I'm just trying to remove the SelectedPayHistory from the EmployeePayHistories list. I'm working with a friend on this project and he said we didn't want to use async for this earlier but hes gone to bed now so I'm not sure why.

Comment: I think you just want `void` - third option in this answer then.

Comment: @brock *i'm just trying to remove the selectedPayHistory from the list*, you are returning the command. if you have to access it async. See Jamiec's 2nd example. I'd add `await Task.Run(() => { /*code*/ });`

Answer (score 1):

Your method returns a `Task`, if you don't want it to be awaitable and return nothing, change return type to void.

```
private void DeleteEmployeePayHistories()
```